# Connecting to MS Access using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ms-access

I tried the following code for establishing a connection with a database(MS Access)..But am getting an error as "Current Recordset does not support updating. This may be a limitation of the provider, or of the selected locktype"

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Insertion</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" >
function AddRecord(form) {
 var cn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
        var strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = C:\\Users\\deepakgopal\\Desktop\\Testing\\Database3.mdb";
        cn.Open(strConn);
        var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
        var SQL = "select count(*) from data";
        rs.Open(SQL, cn);
        alert(rs(0));
        rs.AddNew
        rs.Fields("VDI") = Request.Form("vdi");
        rs.Fields("Staff") = Request.Form("staff");
        rs.Update;   
        rs.Close();
        cn.Close(); 

}

</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0 auto;">
VDI: <input type="text" id="tname" name="vdi" />
<br />
Staff : <input type="text" id="tpwd" name="staff" />
<br />
<input type="button" id="btnsbt" name="btnsbt" value="Login" onclick="AddRecord()" /><br />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI: this code only for Internet Explorer

Comment: You also miss tag <FORM>

Answer (score 5):

The Recordset you are retrieving only contains a single row with a single column containing the count (`COUNT(*)`) of all records in the table. That Recordset contains no other information and is not updatable.

If you want to add records to the table you need to `.Close` that recordset and then re-open it using an SQL command like `SELECT * FROM data` (note: no `COUNT()`). That should allow you to use `.AddNew` and `.Update` to insert new records.